# Uncaught Syntax Error with document.write

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, document

```
document.write("<div id='MainDiv' style='width:600px;margin:auto;'>")
```

While opening the file in the browser an error occur like this

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

What is the solution for this?

Comment: You didn't close the double-quotes for your string.

Comment: Sometimes is good to say what is what you are trying to achieve, this will help you to get more answers, probably what you are trying is not possible or you are doing it "the hard way" (just an advise for next questions)

Comment: I don't see any error there, apart from the missing semicolon after the last parenthesis. Can you please show us more code? I don't think there only is this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.write("<div id='MainDiv' style='width:600px;margin:auto;'>")
```

Comment: sorry for that i missed the quote at end but still it's not clear and the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the double quote at the end of the string. 
It's more code, but I suggest using the JS HTML/DOM API as it makes code much easier to maintain and read than just appending HTML strings.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "MainDiv";
div.style.width = "600px";
div.style.margin = "auto";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').html("<div id='MainDiv' style='width:600px;margin:auto'>");
```

Or:

```
$('body').append("<div id='MainDiv' style='width:600px;margin:auto'>");
```

Or in native JavaScript:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

This creates your div and you can style it now.